# match a value with a string containing that value using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, match, contains

I have this XML file :

```
<Archive Lot="1">
  <DOSSIER>
    <Identifiant>100715</Identifiant>
    <Personne>
      <LIBL>File</LIBL>
    </Personne>
  </DOSSIER>
<DOSSIER>
    <Identifiant>3455667</Identifiant>
    <Personne>
      <LIBL>File2</LIBL>
    </Personne>
  </DOSSIER>
</Archive>
```

I would like to match the node DOSSIER in the with a string that contains the value of Identifiant.

With the following request, it works :

```
Archive/DOSSIER[contains(Identifiant, "100715")]
```

But in my case, I want to match with a string that's not exactly identical but contains the node's value. By doing so, it doesn't match.

`Archive/DOSSIER[contains(Identifiant, "100715_klingon_uiiu")]`

I don't have a match. How do I go about it?
I need to match a node in my XML with external information (a file name) whose value is not exactly identical. But the identifier is there.
Thank you

Comment: While asking an XPath question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0.

Comment: Your sample XML shows no `Identifiant` element that contains `"100715_klingon_uiiu"`, so why would you expect your second XPath to work?

Comment: no, you're right. I expressed my need badly, sorry. I have a process that parses file names, one of which might be 100715_klingon_uiiu.pdf. And I would like to match this variable with the value of Identifier which also contains 100715. When I have a filename that contains the string corresponding to the Identifier node, I want to identify it.
I think my XML input is well-formed. I'd like to work 2.0. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can just swap your `contains()` args around (because you want to check if the first argument string contains the second argument string)...

```xml
/Archive/DOSSIER[contains("100715_klingon_uiiu", Identifiant)]
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you very much. I had misunderstood the documentation for Contains in XPATH.
 Thank you very much.

Comment: Keen eye spotting OP's intent!